# Leading zero issues with pandas read_csv function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of values such as this:

```
123, 234, 345, 456, 567
```

When I do

```
pd.read_csv(dtype = {'column': str})
```

or

```
pd.read_csv(dtype = 'column': object})
```

they both produce values like

```
00123, 00234, 00345, 00456, 00567.
```

I was searching through stackexchange, and people say that you should use `dtype: object`, but it doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read in your data as integers, drop the `dtype`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

If you want to convert the fields to strings, you can apply a `str` transformation with `df.astype`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv').astype(str)
```

Another option would be to use a converter:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', converters={'ColName': str})
```

Comment: lol this is great. It works. I am not sure why dtype didn't work though.

Comment: @JunJang Can't be certain without looking at your data... Has something to do with your data for sure. Maybe you have padding in your fields?

Comment: I think `dtype` should work, maybe your pandas version is old.

Comment: @jezrael Any idea why leading zeros are appended? Bug?

Comment: 2 possible reasons in my opinion - bug or wrong checking (e.g. by excel, not by notepad++) and real data have leading `0`